# Is there any cleaner way to make this amount of comparations in an if clause?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
if (this.state.height !== prevState.height || this.state.hair !== prevState.hair || this.state.weight !== prevState.weight || this.state.eyes !== prevState.eyes || this.state.activity !== prevState.activity || this.state.gender !== prevState.gender || this.state.age !== prevState.age || this.state.wage !== prevState.wage || this.state.city !== prevState.city || this.state.disability !== prevState.disability) {
      this.setState({
        person: {
          height: this.state.height, hair: this.state.hair, weight: this.state.weight, city: this.state.city, eyes: this.state.eyes, disability: this.state.disability,
        },
      });
      this.setState({ showSave: this.state.height.length > 0 && this.state.hair.length > 0 && this.state.activity.length > 0 && this.state.gender.length > 0 && this.state.age.length > 0 && this.state.wage.length > 0 && this.state.overtime.length > 0 && this.state.allowance.length > 0 });
    }
```

What I'm doing is saving the state of a form, the state `person` has the fields that are set above whenever one of them change, and the state `showSave` depends of some of those fields and some others, which is also updated if any of the above fields change.
Also, the state of the class has more fields that are not needed in this `if`.

I'm looking for a cleaner / easier to read way of making all these comparations without needing to add all of this.

Comment: maybe consider including the entire component for context

Comment: hooks could reduce the amount of code you have to write for this

Comment: Please edit the title of your question so it will be easy for others having the same problem to find it

Comment: Do you have a separate state for your form? That would eliminate the need for that first condition. Have each input update the form state, and then when the user submits the form, just replace the person data with the form state.

Comment: @GeoHalkiadakis thanks, I already changed it! Could you suggest a better title if this still doesn´t fit?

Comment: @Andy I don´t, but I guess that's a good way to solve this! Thanks!

Comment: @Mulan sadly I'm forced to use an old react version where there's no hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
* Factory function to define which properties in state you want to compare
* @param {string[]} keys the keys in state you want to compare
* @returns {(state, prevState) => boolean} function to compare state instances
*/
const makeCompareState = (keys) => {
  /**
  * @param {state} current state instance
  * @param {prevState} previous state instance
  * @returns {boolean} true if properties in state are unchanged, false otherwise
  */
  const compareState = (state, prevState) => {
    return keys.every(key => state[key] === prevState[key])
  }

  return compareState;
};


// Define the keys of state you want to compare
const compareState = makeCompareState(["height", "weight", "hair", "city"])

if(compareState(state, prevState) {
 // state has not changed
} else {
 // state has changed
}
```

Note, this solution only works for primitive value since it does a shallow comparison, ie. this will not work for comparing objects, functions, or arrays.

Alternatively, you can use a third-party solution if you don't mind the extra bundle size, like `dequal`, to do a deep comparison of `state`

```
import { isEqual } from "dequal";

if(isEqual(state, prevState)) {
  // state is unchanged
} else {
  // state has changed
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since the whole component is just a big form I think I'll go with the second one for the first comparation, since I want to update it almost always and it's not wrong if it's updates just once time without need.

Also, probably going to implement the first method for the second, since the fields there are more variable, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use loadash library isEqual method for this. It deep compare 2 objects.This way it is more cleaner.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
if(!_.isEqual(this.state, prevState)){//...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is inconsistent. It's signature is either

```
{
  gender:any,
  height:any,
  hair:any,
  weight:any,
  city:any,
  eyes:any,
  allowance:any,
  wage:any,
  overtime:any,
  disability:any
}
```

or

```
{
  showSave:boolean
}
```

I would **strongly** encourage you upgrade to at least **React 16.8**, convert your app into functional components wherever possible, and use `useReducer` instead.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  gender: '',
  height: '',
  hair: '',
  weight: '',
  city: '',
  eyes: '',
  allowance: '',
  wage: '',
  overtime: '',
  disability: '',
  showSave: false
};

const characterStateReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'set' && action.attributes) {
    // copy from previous state
    const newState = { ...state };

    for (const attr in action.attributes) {
      newState[attr] = action.attributes[attr];
    }        

    // update showSave
    newState.showSave = 
      newState.height.length > 0 && 
      newState.hair.length > 0 && 
      newState.activity.length > 0 && 
      newState.gender.length > 0 && 
      newState.age.length > 0 && 
      newState.wage.length > 0 && 
      newState.overtime.length > 0 && 
      newState.allowance.length > 0;

    return newState;
  } else {
    // NOTE: returning same state won't trigger updates
    return state;
  }
}
```

and use this as

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(characterStateReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
```

where dispatch is called like

```
dispatch({ 
  type:'set',
  attributes: {
    height:"5'10''"
  }
});
```